# if statement in mysql not ignoring a field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a set of records which are calendar entries, each with a 'scope' which defines who can or cannot see them

in my query, I don't want the userID to matter if the calendar scope is set to all, so that all entries with all are visible, as well ones specific to that user

what do I put in the statement in place of the ?

I've tried userID = null,  userID = 0, no good.

Here is the query

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE IF ( calendarScope = 'all', ? , userID = " . ( (int) $user->getUserID() ) . " )
```

Comment: Why are you using a `?` placeholder for one value but not the other?

Comment: @tadman: I was confused too, but that "`?`" isn't a placeholder for a bind variable substitution, that's just the part of the expression OP wants to fill in to get the statement to work.

Comment: @spencer7593 Good catch. I was distracted by the terrifying string concatenation approach to composing queries.

Comment: @tadman: I know what you mean, tadman, I was distracted too... it's so much easier to read and figure out what code is doing when the SQL statement is just a plain old string. Composing SQL statements on the fly using string concatenation adds an (unnecessary) order of complexity; and it makes for way more cracks for the bugs to hide in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expresssion in the WHERE clause is evaluated as a boolean. A value of 0 evaluates as FALSE, a non-zero value is TRUE, and a NULL evaluates as NULL.

I think you want a query that looks something like this:

```
SELECT c.* 
  FROM `calendar` c
 WHERE c.calendarScope = 'all'
    OR ( 
         c.userID = 777  -- the other condition(s) you want to check
       )
```

If the "`c.calendarScope = 'all'` " expression evaluates as `TRUE`, then it doesn't matter if the part after the "`OR`" is true or not. The entire " `TRUE OR (whatever)` " expression is going to evaluate as `TRUE`.

Otherwise (i.e. if "`c.calendarScope = 'all'`" evaluates to `FALSE` or `NULL`, then part after the "`OR`" comes into play. We'd need that to evaluate as `TRUE` in order for the row to be returned.

**NOTE:** I suggest you get the SQL query working first, before you turn it into a PHP string; and I recommend you use prepared statements with bind variables, over string substitution.